# How to make this code work? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
 var dateClasses = $('.dateClass'); // array of all your dateClasses
 var contentClasses = $('.contentClass'); // array of all your contentClasses

 for(var i=0; i< Math.min(dateClasses.length,contentClasses.length); i++) {
 var frame = $("<div>", {class: "frame"}); // create your frame node
 var timeLineDate = $("<span>",{class: "timeline-date"});
 var timeLineContent = $("<div>",{class: "timeline-content"});

 //Append DateClass to your timeline-data:
 timeLineData.append(dateClasses[i]);

  //Append ContentClass to your timeline-content:
 timeLineContent.append(contentClasses[i]);

 //Append all to your frame
 frame.append(timeLineData);
 frame.append(timeLineContent);
 }
```

And:

```
<span class="dateClass">date1</span>
<span class="dateClass">date2</span>
<span class="dateClass">date3</span>
<div class="contentClass">content1</div>
<div class="contentClass">content2</div>
<div class="contentClass">content3</div>
```

But I'm not sure why it wouldn't work, any advise? :/

http://jsfiddle.net/8qrLh2wz/

Thanks for your time

**Edit:** 
**I apologize to everyone, I submitted the post too quickly** I totally deserve the downvotes. 
What I'd like to do is indeed (as one of you mentioned) move the `dateClass` elements to `timeline-date`, and `contentClass` to `timeline-content`. However I need one `frame` per `dateClass` and `contentClass` group of elements: that means there should be **3** `frame` in total

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What does it do? What do you expect it to do? It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Questions should ALWAYS describe what the intended behavior is (what the code is supposed to do) AND describe what you observe the code doing and/or what errors you see.  You should not assume we can figure out from your code what you're trying to accomplish.  Describe that in words.

Comment: Open the Developer Tools in your browser with the fiddle page and click the Run button. The first thing you will see is that `$` is undefined. You can fix that with the Frameworks & Extensions dropdown. Then click Run again. The next error will be that `timeLineData` is not defined. Fix that and try again, and keep fixing errors as you find them. Once you learn how to use your Developer Tools this will start to get a lot easier.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j5sc5sy1/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is to move the `dateClass` elements to `timeline-date` and `contentClass` to `timeline-content`.

But in your code you are creating new elements, but they are not added to the dom so try

```
var dateClasses = $('.dateClass'); // array of all your dateClasses
var contentClasses = $('.contentClass'); // array of all your contentClasses

$('.frame .timeline-date').append(dateClasses);
$('.frame .timeline-content').append(contentClasses);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j5sc5sy1/5/)

If you want to keep your loop

```
var dateClasses = $('.dateClass'); // array of all your dateClasses
var contentClasses = $('.contentClass'); // array of all your contentClasses

var timeLineData =$('.frame .timeline-date');
var timeLineContent =$('.frame .timeline-content');

for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(dateClasses.length, contentClasses.length); i++) {
    //Append DateClass to your timeline-data:
    timeLineData.append(dateClasses[i]);

    //Append ContentClass to your timeline-content:
    timeLineContent.append(contentClasses[i]);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j5sc5sy1/)

Comment: Thank you @ArunPJohny , I just updated the question with the issue I'm experiencing, I'd need one `frame` per `timeline-date` and `timeline-content` group of elements, how could I achieve it?

Comment: @DanielFelipe http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j5sc5sy1/6/ ?

Comment: Thank you @ArunPJohny, it is working perfectly!, I'm having one issue, and is that it is rendering after the `body` tag, it is not rendered where the script is, so I was wondering if instead of _creating_ the divs, do you think there is the possibility to _append_ the elements to an already existing divs? **Or**, at least specify where the `frame` div will be created in the document, an existing div in the page, such as `parent-frame` for example

Comment: @DanielFelipe http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j5sc5sy1/7/

Comment: I should have definitely read the last append, how could I miss it? :/ Thank you very much, it worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

First at all, your question is not clear, what it should do?

Second, there is a typo on your code, your var name is "timeLineDate", but you're calling timeLineData twice.

**Updated**

```
<span class="dateClass">date1</span>
<span class="dateClass">date2</span>
<span class="dateClass">date3</span>
<div class="contentClass">content1</div>
<div class="contentClass">content2</div>
<div class="contentClass">content3</div>

var dateClasses = $('.dateClass'); // array of all your dateClasses
var contentClasses = $('.contentClass'); // array of all your contentClasses
var countElements = Math.min(dateClasses.length, contentClasses.length);

for(var i = 0; i < countElements; i++) {
     var frame = $("<div>", {class: "frame"}); // create your frame node
     var timeLineDate = $("<div>",{class: "timeline-date"});
     var timeLineContent = $("<div>",{class: "timeline-content"});

     //Append DateClass to your timeline-data:
     timeLineDate.append(dateClasses[i]);

      //Append ContentClass to your timeline-content:
     timeLineContent.append(contentClasses[i]);

     //Append all to your frame
     frame.append(timeLineDate);
     frame.append(timeLineContent);
     $("body").append(frame);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j8229w4v/2/

Comment: I apologize, I made the post too quick, I'm sorry. What I'd like to do is indeed move the dateClass elements to timeline-date, and contentClass  to timeline-content. However I need one `frame` per dateClass and contentClass elements: that means there should be 3 `frame` in total

Comment: Structurally, you want something like this:

    <div class="frame">
        <div class="timeline-date">
            <span class="dateClass">date1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-content">
            <div class="contentClass">content1</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="frame">
        <div class="timeline-date">
            <span class="dateClass">date2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-content">
            <div class="contentClass">content2</div>
        </div>
    </div>

...

Comment: Yes, indeed, that is exactly.

Comment: Please, check my update. I think it should work.